# Какой нужен цикл для вывода json?

Tags: json, javascript

Есть JSON:

```
    "success":1,
      "return":{
        "343152":{
          "type":"sell",
          "amount":1
        },
        "343153":{
          "type":"buy",
          "amount":2
        }
      }
```

Как его представить в виде:

```
    <ul>
       <li>343152:</li>
       <li>
          <ul>
             <li>type: sell</li>
             <li>amount: 1</li>
          </ul>
       </li>

       <li>343153:</li>
       <li>
          <ul>
             <li>type: buy</li>
             <li>amount: 2</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

используя js

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

```
var items = '';
$.getJSON("/ajax/", "q=" + query, function(response) {
  $.each(response, function(i,val) {
    items += '<li id="' + i + '">' + val + '</li>';
  });
  $('#foo').html(items);
});
```